# Using bash to generate random IPs in Curl

Tags: bash, shell, ip, ip-address, command-substitution

How to use random ip address in Curl request,I'm using this code and worked

```
printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n" "$((RANDOM % 256))" "$((RANDOM % 256))" "$((RANDOM % 256))" "$((RANDOM % 256))"
```

but when use this code in Curl request and test on http://ifconfig.me not worked

```
curl --header 'X-Forwarded-For: printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n" "$((RANDOM % 256))" "$((RANDOM % 256))" "$((RANDOM % 256))" "$((RANDOM % 256))"' http://ifconfig.me
```

Comment: Can you clarify "not worked" ? It returns the IP

Comment: @dash-o return  and show my local Ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is suggest to use command substitution. Replace

```
curl --header 'X-Forwarded-For: printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n" "$((RANDOM % 256))" "$((RANDOM % 256))" "$((RANDOM % 256))" "$((RANDOM % 256))"' http://ifconfig.me
```

with

```
curl --header "X-Forwarded-For: $(printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n" "$((RANDOM % 256))" "$((RANDOM % 256))" "$((RANDOM % 256))" "$((RANDOM % 256))")" http://ifconfig.me
              ^                 ^^                                                                                                      ^^
```

I switched from `'...'` to `"..."` and from `printf "..."` to `$(printf "...")`.

---

See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)